# Why is disqus showing a small "blog" link next to my post?

Tags: blogs, disqus

I'm trying to use Disqus with my blog and I'm right now testing it on localhost and I found there is a small "blog" link next to my blog post.  Click on the link it takes you to Disqus website.  I couldn't find a way to get rid of it, could someone point out what I'm not doing right or how to remove it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Disqus has this line of code

```
<a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink" style="display:block">blog comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
```

The only thing I added to fix the issue is adding the following inline style

```
style="display:block"
```

IE9 shows it correctly without my addition, but chrome shows it incorrectly without it for some reason.